# Unable to build firebase gradle in Android studio

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I am adding Firebase database gradle into my **Android Project,** but gradle is unable to build.I added Firebase gradle in my app gradle and one google gradle in **Project gradle**  I am getting this message:

[image]

this is my app gradle

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "iamrajendra.github.io"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.2'

}
```

and this is my project gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
         classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Have a look at this https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem. the problem is the version of library

**working library**

```
implementation'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.0'
```

If the tutorial android library version is 11.01  but this version is not working in android studio

**not working library**

```
com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.2
```

In tutorial gradle dependencies are wrongly written.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup

Answer (score 1):

Add this under the last line in your app gradle .. in the bottom of the file

```
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Did you try to Update Google Play services and Google Repository in SDK Manager?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this dependencies,

// FirebaseUI Database only
 compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:2.0.1'

// Single target that includes all FirebaseUI libraries above
 compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:2.0.1'

Comment: compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:2.0.1'
 I added this gable but not working